# Upgrade node js tcp server to tls server fro xmpp chat application

Tags: node.js, xmpp

I am facing problem to upgrade my node.js tcp server to tls server. right now its use for plain chatting  using xmpp. Now I have to build it tls/ssl secure. please help.. thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks for replying Ravi... I am trying to replace net module to tls module. But I am not able to understand the server_key.pem, and server_cert.pem. I also generated these keys from openssl. can you suggest me where should I start?

Comment: which module you're using for that?

Comment: I ma using tls for that.

Comment: hmmm, you need to add valid OpenSSL certificates, check this https://github.com/pghalliday/tls-tunnel, there is a test folder, which has script for generating certs, you can use that.